# convert little Endian file into big Endian

Tags: java

how can i convert a liitle Endian binary file into big Endian binary file. i have a binary binary written in C and i am reading this file in Java with DataInputStream which reads in big endian format.i also had a look on ByteBuffer class but have no idea how to use it to get my desired result. please help.

thanks alot

Comment: Endian, not indian. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Opening eggs can get quite confusing I see :-)

Comment: yes you guys are right. in hurry you can make mistakes but don,t worry i,ll learn more with my mistakes. thanks for pointing me out about my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after Googling so much i have found a apache Jar file which has SwappedDataInputStream Class.
org.apache.commons.io.input.SwappedDataInputStream.
this class made my results accurate. for full detail of that class see.

http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/SwappedDataInputStream.html

Answer (score 14):

Opening NIO FileChannel:

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("myfile.bin");
FileChannel fc = fs.getChannel();
```

Setting ByteBuffer endianness (used by [get|put]Int(), [get|put]Long(), [get|put]Short(), [get|put]Double())

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(0x10000);
buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); // or ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN
```

Reading from FileChannel to ByteBuffer

```
fc.read(buf);
buf.flip();
// here you take data from the buffer by either of getShort(), getInt(), getLong(), getDouble(), or get(byte[], offset, len)
buf.compact();
```

To correctly handle endianness of the input you need to know exactly what is stored in the file and in what order (so called protocol or format).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`EndianUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/EndianUtils.html) from [Apache Commons I/O](http://commons.apache.org/io/):

It has `static` methods like [`long readSwappedLong(InputStream input)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/EndianUtils.html#readSwappedLong%28java.io.InputStream%29) that can do all the swapping for you. It also has overloads that uses a `byte[]` as input, as well as `write` counterpart (to `OutputStream` or `byte[]`). It also has non-I/O methods like [`int swapInteger(int value)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/EndianUtils.html#swapInteger%28int%29) methods that can do conversion of plain Java primitives.

The package also has many useful utility classes like [`FilenameUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html), [`IOUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html), etc.

#### See also

- [Most useful free third party Java libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130095/most-useful-free-third-party-java-libraries)

Answer (score 2):

The two functions below swap between the endianness of a 2 and 4 bytes.

```
static short Swap_16(short x) {

    return (short) ((((short) (x) & 0x00ff) << 8) | (((short) (x) & 0xff00) >> 8));
}

static int Swap_32(int x) {
    return ((((int) (x) & 0x000000ff) << 24)
            | (((int) (x) & 0x0000ff00) << 8)
            | (((int) (x) & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) | (((int) (x) & 0xff000000) >> 24));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should read every 4 bytes and simply reverse their order.

Comment: @Recurse According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness, you would be referring to mixed-endian or middle-endian

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a blog post on doing exactly this. On how you can convert binary files between endianness. Adding it here for future reference for anyone coming here.

You can get this done from the following simple code

```
FileChannel fc = (FileChannel) Files.newByteChannel(Paths.get(filename), StandardOpenOption.READ);
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int)fc.size());
byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
fc.read(byteBuffer);
byteBuffer.flip();

Buffer buffer = byteBuffer.asShortBuffer();
short[] shortArray = new short[(int)fc.size()/2];
((ShortBuffer)buffer).get(shortArray);

byteBuffer.clear();
byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
ShortBuffer shortOutputBuffer = byteBuffer.asShortBuffer();
shortOutputBuffer.put(shortArray);

FileChannel out = new FileOutputStream(outputfilename).getChannel();
out.write(byteBuffer);
out.close();
```

For detailed information about how this works you can refer to the original blog post - http://pulasthisupun.blogspot.com/2016/06/reading-and-writing-binary-files-in.html

Or the code is available at - https://github.com/pulasthi/binary-format-converter