# How to read float array from binary file in android?

Tags: android, floating-point

I have a binary file I wish to read for my android app. the file's content was saved and written in "float" format.

How do I read this data to a float array?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [DataInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html)'s readFloat method. Loop until you get an EOFException.

Comment: Thank you. I also had to change the Endianness. This link was usefull: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438415/convert-little-endian-file-into-big-endian)